# PHP 7.4 session_start and setcookie (session not start and cookie not set)

Tags: php, session, setcookie

I have two questions to ask, on the same topic.
In a new server (debian 10) whith standard parameters in php.ini (7.4) and standard apache2 configurations, the following code doesn't work.

```
session_name('mySiteSession');
session_start();
$params = [
     'lifetime' => time()+600, 
     'path' => '/crm', 
     'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
     'secure' => 0,
     'httponly' => 0,
     'samesite' => 'Strict'
    ];
```

setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), $params["lifetime"], $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);

The cookie correctly set only the name, path and domain parameter, the others remain false and none.
This is the first part of the problem, the second part, I tried with the parameters in session_start

```
session_name('mySiteSession');
$session_options = [
    'cookie_lifetime' => time()+600,
    'cookie_path' => '/crm', 
    'cookie_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 
    'cookie_secure' => 0, 
    'cookie_samesite' => 'Strict', 
    'cookie_httponly' => 1, 
    'read_and_close'  => true
    ];
session_start($session_options);
```

set the cookies correctly but the session does not start and if I repeat session_start () without parameters

> Notice: session_start (): A session had already been started -
> ignoring...

but
var_dump($_SESSION) is void.

Best regards

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar weird issue where $_SESSION is always empty due to PHPSESSID cookie beign absent from the browser (yesterday it was working, goddamnit). Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, even if I had set `session_start()` and `setcookie(...)` directly at the beginning of the script. A new session was started with every call because the cookie was not set.

The solution for me was now `session_cookie_params(...)` first, followed by `session_start()`. `session_cookie_params` hast to be called **before** `session_start`!

[Read about session_cookie_params() on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for further details on parameters and notation.

```
session_set_cookie_params([
  'lifetime' => 900, // expires in 15 minutes
  'path' => '/', // any path on same domain
  'secure' => true,
  'httponly' =>true
]);

session_start();
```

Attention: in my case, 'secure' must be set to false to work properly on local testing! Don't forget to switch true when going into production. Domain defaults to current.

This cookie will expire after the lifetime in seconds no matter how often the person comes back in the meantime. If you want your cookie to refresh automatically on every visit, you can do this like this:

```
session_start();

$currentParams = session_get_cookie_params();
$sessionID = session_id();

setcookie(
  'PHPSESSID', // ------------------- name
  $sessionID, // -------------------- value/ID
  time() + 900, // ------------------ expires in 15 minutes
  $currentParams['path'],   // ------ path
  $currentParams['domain'], // ------ domain
  true, // -------------------------- secure
  true  // -------------------------- http-only
);
```

If this still does not fix it for you, you can try to buffer each output (which probably sent headers before your session settings) and locate the problem. See `ob_start` ([on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)) and `ob_get_clean` ([on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)) for example.

Comment: I had a migration from php 7.1 to 7.4 and ran into the issue that session_set_cookie_params had a different way of setting it's parameters directly instead of an array as it is since 7.3 onwards. This might be useful for anybody migration older code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `session_start()` on the very first line of your file. I think that that is your issue.

Comment: Yes, I didn't write it here but it is.
Thank you